# How to use Resources of from another project in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a solution under which so many WPF applications and class library projects are there.
I want to use icon in another project which is under Resources folder in other WPF application. 
how can I achieve this ? I do not want to copy same images over and over in all different projects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [pack URI syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to refer resources. Somethning like this:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Another.Assembly.Name;component/PathToResourceInAnotherProject/YourImage.png"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes,Microsoft makes that possible for you, as long as Project ABC has a reference to Project XYZ.

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Project XYZ;component/YourSubFolder/YourResourceFile.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Then you can just use the Resources defined in YourResourceFile.xaml.

Comment: It works as per your suggestion! I want to try something more and let you know what I want to achieve is possible or not

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/Project XYZ;` as per your above statement

Comment: Well it should be but I understand the what he wants to tell me :)